# What does $A\cap T^{-n}(B)$ imply about $T^n(A)\cap B$?

Tags: ergodic-theory

From https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kraai101/LectureNotesMM-2.pdf

example 1.8.4 (multiplication by 2 modulo 1), page 29.

What do they do at the second equality $\lambda(A\cap T^{-n} B) = \frac{1}{\lambda(A)}\lambda(T^n A\cap B)$?

I'm sure that they don't use the fact that $T^n(B)=[0,1)$ because that information is already used in the third equality.

They apply $T$ on $A$ and $T^{n}(B)$, this $n$ times, so $T$ looks like making any set $\lambda$-twice as big. But this is easily seen not to be true, take $[0,1)$.

I hope anyone can answer this, thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't true that $T^n(B)=[0,1)$.  The assumptions are that $A$ is a dyadmic inteverval of order $n$ (so $T^n(A)=[0,1)$) and $B$ is $T$ invariant, i.e., $T^-1(B)=B$.  The first inequality is $T$-invariance of $B$, I'm still not sure about the second, but the third has a problem: since $T^n(A)$ is the entire space, and $\lambda(A)=1/2^n$, either the $1/\lambda(A)$ should be $\lambda(A)$ or the $1/2^n$ should be $2^n$.